# B-spline weighted least squares fit

Tags: least-squares, spline

Can someone please point to an easy to read source for Bspline curve fitting with weighted least squares. Basically I want to fit a function, and I have some points which are more important then others. I do not want an interpolation, but rather a smooth fit. 
Any code or library is also very welcome.

Answer (score 2):

There is code (plus all the underlying mathematics) in "The NURBS Book" by Piegl and Tiller. [Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00YZMBA76)

Alternatively, theory and code is available [here](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/BSplineCurveLeastSquaresFit.pdf).

Or, try [here](http://www.cs.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/INT-APP/CURVE-APP-global.html).

Comment: Over $300!!! Ridiculous.

Comment: I agree. Don't know why it's so expensive. It's a fairly large book, but not especially beautiful. There are other editions listed on Amazon for around $100, which is still over-priced, in my view. The book is available in many libraries. And, for people who no respect for intellectual property rights, I have seen "free" pdf copies on the internet.